# Orientation of Point form matrix center in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, geometry

In **Matlab** I've got a simple 2D matrix. I would like to calculate the orientation of certain points of that matrix from the center of that very same matrix. Maybe with a simple diagram it's clearer:
[image]

I've got several points (point in blue, green, yellow and brown). I would like to calculate the angles of orientation of each point. So p1 (blue) will be 45 degrees, yellow will be 180, brown will be 250-270 and green 0 degrees. It looks pretty easy however I've been stuck with this for a long time and my code doesn't works well in all situations.

In this example I'm showing a matrix with a pair number of rows and columns (my matrix will always be a square matrix), so what should be done in those cases in which the matrix has odd dimensions?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cart2pol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cart2pol.html) to convert into polar coordinates, example for your blue point at position (3,3) from the center:

```
[angle, ~]=cart2pol(3,3);
angle=

    0.7854
```

which is the angle in radians.

You can create a dataset with your cartesian coordinates (clockwise from the blue one):

```
Coordinates=[3 3; 4 0; -1 -4; -4 0; -2, 2];
[angle, dist]=cart2pol(Coordinates(:, 1), Coordinates(:, 2));
```

And convert the angle in degrees:

```
DegAngle=(angle/(2*pi))*360;

DegAngle =

   45.0000
         0
 -104.0362
  180.0000
  135.0000
```

Note: to get the position of each point relative to the center you can use `CoordTopLeft -floor(size(YourMatrix))` where `CoordTopLeft` are the standard coordinates relative to the top left corner.

Comment: Yes.Thank you. For a more complete code I've written DegAngle=mod((angle/(2*pi))*360,360);

Comment: And what about if I don't have a squared matrix? How can I fix the center and calculate the relative position of each point (the parameter I pass to cart2pol)

Comment: @karl71 you are welcome. You mean if the pixels are not square? There is no problem if your matrix is not square, only if the axis are not orthonormal.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function which takes in two points and gives an angle between them as an output.

```
function desiredAngle=findAngle2Points(centerPt,pt2)

x1=centerPt(1);x2=pt2(1);y1=centerPt(2);y2=pt2(2);
angle = mod(atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1),2*pi);
angleInD=angle*180/pi;
%or, alternatively use atan2d as follows
%angleInD = mod(atan2d(y2-y1,x2-x1),360);
desiredAngle=mod((360-angleInD),360); %Added mod to give 0 angle for the green 
                                      %point instead of 360.

end
```

For the blue point (`center=[4 4], pt2=[6.5 1.5]`), the angle comes out to be 45 degrees. For yellow and orange, it is respectively 180 and 262 degrees. The formula for angle between two 2-D points was taken from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/151925). This is numerically more stable than `acos` formula. You can read the detailed discussion on the mentioned link.